# Input confirmation batch file

Tags: batch-file

So i was writing a Batch file, and i made a file that you can choose an answer by a question, and its saves it automaticly to a file. But i want to make something before it saves it to a file, to let people confirm their choices. Simplified, i have it like this:

```
Rem Question 1 appearance
:q1
cls
Echo.
Echo Please select your age:
Echo ==================
Echo A) younger than 18
Echo B) 18-30
Echo C) 30-45
Echo D) older than 45
Echo.
Echo.

Rem Question 1 in- and output settings
:q1.2
set INPUT=
set /p INPUT=Answer:
if "%INPUT%"=="A" Echo You chose an age of less than 18. & pause & goto q2
if "%INPUT%"=="B" Echo You chose an age of 18-30. & pause & goto q2
if "%INPUT%"=="C" Echo You chose an age of 30-45. & pause & goto q2
if "%INPUT%"=="D" Echo You chose an age of older than 45. & pause & goto q2
Echo Please enter a valid answer!
goto q1.2

Rem question 2 appearance
:q2
Echo Answer: %INPUT% >>Question1answers.txt
cls
Echo.
Echo Please select your favourite colour:
Echo ==========================
Echo A) Blue
Echo B) Red
Echo C) Green
Echo D) Yellow
Echo E) Other
Echo.
Echo.

Rem Question 2 in- and output settings
:q2.1
set INPUT=
set /p INPUT=Answer:
if "%INPUT%"=="A" Echo You chose blue.&pause&goto end
if "%INPUT%"=="B" Echo You chose red.&pause&goto end
if "%INPUT%"=="C" Echo You chose green.&pause&goto end
if "%INPUT%"=="D" Echo You chose yellow.&pause&goto end
if "%INPUT%"=="E" Echo You chose something else.&pause&goto end
Echo Please enter a valid answer!
goto q2.1
```

So i ask you to not reply with the full code, maybe a little piece so i can learn from it and put it in myself, you know? Thanks!

Edit:

So now i added this part:

```
:confirmation
cls
Echo Please make sure this is your data:
if "%INPUTT%"=="A" Echo You chose an age of less than 18.
if "%INPUTT%"=="B" Echo You chose an age of 18-30.
if "%INPUTT%"=="C" Echo You chose an age of 30-45.
if "%INPUTT%"=="D" Echo You chose an age of older than 45.
echo.
if "%INPUT%"=="A" Echo You chose blue as your favourite colour.
if "%INPUT%"=="B" Echo You chose red as your favourite colour.
if "%INPUT%"=="C" Echo You chose green as your favourite colour.
if "%INPUT%"=="D" Echo You chose yellow as your favourite colour.
if "%INPUT%"=="E" Echo You chose something else as your favourite colour.

choice /m "Is this your data?" /d Y
if %errorlevel%==1 goto q1

Echo Answer: %INPUTT% >>Question1answers.txt
Echo Answer: %INPUT% >>Question2answers.txt
```

So i started debugging and when i came to the part it was wrong, it let me through and still saved my input. it kind of ignores the part of
    if %errorlevel%==1 goto q1
so what do i do now?

Comment: So you create another question to confirm their choices.  Either do that with another `set /p` or use the `choice` command.

Comment: @squash Oh wait haha i forgot to say that i want to show them the answers they have given and then they can say yes or no if they want to start again

Comment: So make a first try on it and let us see ;)

Comment: @JeroenSteens, I see you got this figured out but what was stopping you from showing the user what they entered.  It is a basic ECHO command. Nothing special about it.  Or as you were shown below you can use them within the choice command and you could even use them in a SET /P command.

Answer (score 1):

since you ask for a short snippet, this should do what you want:

```
set /p "age=Enter your age: "
choice /M "Your age is %age%, correct?"
if %errorlevel%==1 goto :correct
echo false
goto :eof
:correct
echo true
```

Comment: please check my Question again, i added a new thing after implenting your solution.

Comment: enter `choice /m "Is this your data?" /d Y` at the prompt and read the errormessage.

Comment: You mean cmd? because i tried that, it said i forgot to use /t and when i added that, it still not works.

Comment: "still not works" Hm - strange errormessage... You may have to adapt `Y` when you are not working with an English Windows (for me, it's `J`) (or use the `/C` option). And of course `/t` expects a value.

Comment: So i have this:
    choice /m "Is this your data?" /c YN /t 60 /d Y

    if %errorlevel%==1 goto q1

And it still denies when i choose No (It is kind of messed up but those commands are one above the other)

Comment: wait - an `errorlevel` of 1 means, the _first_ choice has been selected (that's `Y` - are you sure, the user should be asked again, if he confirmed with Yes? Selecting `N` woud give an `%errorlevel%` of `2`.